change the animation after the current one has ended
I'm currently working on a React Native project where I'm implementing animations using the react-native-animatable library. I've managed to create a sequence of animations that loop indefinitely using setInterval. However, I'm looking for a more efficient way to manage the timing of these animations without relying on setInterval.
Objective:
I aim to create a series of animations that transition seamlessly one after another without using setInterval. Each animation should start after the previous one ends.
code:
    import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
    const animations = [
      { to: { left: '42%', top: '15%' }, from: { left: '5%', top: '15%' }, easing: 'linear' },
      { to: { left: '40%', top: '49%' }, from: { left: '47%', top: '20%' }, easing: 'linear' },
      { from: { left: '40%', top: '49%' }, to: { left: '47%', top: '20%' }, easing: 'linear' },
      { to: { left: '80%', top: '15%' }, from: { left: '50%', top: '15%' }, easing: 'linear' },
    ];
    const App = () => {
 
      useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          setCurrentAnimation((prevAnimation) => (prevAnimation + 1) % animations.length);
        }, 4000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, []);
    };
    {animations.map((animation, index) => (
              <Animatable.View
                key={index}
                animation={animation}
                duration={4000}
                iterationCount="infinite"
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  opacity: index === currentAnimation ? 1 : 0,
                }}
              >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleEnvelopePress}>
                  <FontAwesome name="envelope" size={24} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </Animatable.View>
            ))}

Now it works with setInterval
      useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          setCurrentAnimation((prevAnimation) => (prevAnimation + 1) % animations.length);
        }, 4000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, []);


Using onAnimationEnd doesn't help

I have created an example (https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/chain-react-animation) for react-reanimated, maybe this gives you an idea how to implement a similar solution for react-native-animatable.
